# Range Lookup for 2 Dataframes (with 2 input vectors)

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, data-cleaning

can someone help me?  Here are the details below.

**Sample Dataframe 1:**

```
Latitude  Longitude
   12.10       4.10
   12.20       4.20
   12.30       4.50
```

**Dataframe 2:**

```
ID     Latitude1 Latitude2 Longitude1 Longitude2
ABC         11.5     12.15        3.9       4.15
DEF        12.17     12.25       4.17       4.25
GHI        12.27     12.45       4.45       4.48
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Latitude Longitude   ID
   12.10      4.10  ABC           
   12.20      4.20  DEF
   12.30      4.50   NA
```

3rd row in the output is NA since it's Longitude value is not in between the range given in dataframe2.

**Attempted Solution:**
I created a function and used DPLYR but I can only do range lookup for one vector (Latitude).

```
getValue <- function(x,data) {
  tmp <- data %>%
    filter(Latitude1 <= x, x <= Latitude2) %>%
    filter(row_number() == 1)
  return(tmp$ID)
}
data_interval <- sapply(df1$Latitude, getValue, data=df2)
```

**df1 dput:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Latitude = c(12.1, 12.2, 12.3), Longitude = c(4.1, 
4.2, 4.5)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

**df2 dput:**

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), Latitude1 = c(11.5, 
12.17, 12.27), Latitude2 = c(12.15, 12.25, 12.45), Longitude1 = c(3.9, 
4.17, 4.45), Longitude2 = c(4.15, 4.25, 4.48)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Allan Cameron, I'm a new member.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I tried. For longitude and latitude in each row in `df1`, you want to run logical checks using the lon / lat values in each row in `df2`. For each row in `df1`, I created a data frame containing logical values. Each data frame has three rows and two columns. Then, I identified which row in each data frame has TRUE for both longitude and latitude. Using this index, I obtained desired `ID` in `df2`

```
library(tidyverse)

map2_dfr(.x = df1$Latitude,
         .y = df1$Longitude,
         .f = function(x, y){
                tibble(lat = between(x, df2$Latitude1, df2$Latitude2),
                       lon = between(y, df2$Longitude1, df2$Longitude2)) %>% 
                mutate(subid = 1:n())},
         .id = "id") %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
filter(lat == TRUE & lon == TRUE) %>% 
transmute(ID = df2$ID[subid]) -> out

out
#  id    ID   
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 1     ABC  
#2 2     DEF
```

Next step was to join `out` with `df1`. Since there is no match for the third row, you see NA.

```
mutate(df1,
       id = as.character(1:n())) %>% 
left_join(out, by = "id") %>% 
select(-id)

  Latitude Longitude   ID
1     12.1       4.1  ABC
2     12.2       4.2  DEF
3     12.3       4.5 <NA>
```

Comment: Hi @jazzurro, thanks for the input. However, I encounter this error when running the first part of the code:

**Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=43064]**

Comment: @MarcAtanante I do not have your actual data. Hence I do not know what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who helped. I tried a different approach using "SQLDF" and it worked perfectly. Take note that I'm comparing a 2.4 million row dataframe with a 43,000 row lookup dataframe so it took me 3 hours to run.

```
sql_way_test <- function(data,lookup){
  data<-sqldf("select A.*,B.ID from
              data A left join lookup B 
              ON ((A.Latitude >= B.Latitude1 and A.Latitude < B.Latitude2) and
              (A.Longitude >= B.Longitude1 and A.Longitude < B.Longitude2))")
  data
}

df_SQLway <- sql_way_test(data = df1, df2)
```